# UILabel as subview of UIBarButtonItem.customView not dimming when presenting view controller

Tags: ios, uinavigationitem, rightbarbuttonitem, uibuttonbaritem

I have an issue where UILabel in the navigation bar is not being tinted properly when a view controller is presented modally.

The UILabel is in the navigation bar, as a child view of a UIButton, which is a child view of the UIBarButtonItem, which is the rightBarButtonItem of the navigation controller; View hierarchy:

```
rightBarButtonItem
-UIBarButtonItem
--UIButton <-- this is UIButtonTypeSystem, with a cart image. Tinting properly.
---UILabel <-- this is the # of items in the cart. Not tinting.
```

To be clear, everything works fine except the label tint during a presented modal. Before the view controller is presented, the cart is tinted blue and so is the label containing the # of cart items. When the modal is presented, the cart image dims, but the label stays blue.

I'd post images, but I do not have enough reputation, sorry.

What I have tried:

- Setting the tint color on the label
- Setting the `label.userInteractionEnabled = NO`
- Setting the `label.tintAdjustmentMode = UIViewTintAdjustmentModeDimmed` to all available values (none of which helped)
- Subclassing UIButton and drawing the # cart items during `drawRect`
- During the view controller presentation, finding the label in the `navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.customView` hierarchy and setting the tintAdjustmentMode manually.

Nothing has worked. I'm out of ideas...

Here is the code where I am creating the UIBarButtonItem:

```
+(UIBarButtonItem*) getCartBarButtonItemWithDelegate:(id)delegate {

    NSInteger cartItems = [[DataHandler sharedInstance]cartQuantity];

    NSString* num = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long) cartItems];
    NSString* cartImageToUse = @"cart_toolbar_button_icon";
    CGFloat fontSize = 11;
    UILabel *label = nil;

    if(cartItems  > 0) {
        if([num length] > 1) {
            cartImageToUse = @"cartnumbered_toolbar_button2_icon";
            fontSize = 10;
            label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(7, -3, 16, 12)];
        } else {
            cartImageToUse = @"cartnumbered_toolbar_button_icon";
            label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(7.5, -3, 16, 12)];
        }        

        [label setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:fontSize]];
        [label setText: num ];
        [label setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
        [label setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    }

    // attempt at sub classing UIButton and drawing the number of items in the drawRect method
    //CartButton *button =  [CartButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
    UIButton *button =  [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
    [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed: cartImageToUse] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addTarget:delegate action:@selector(handleCartTouch:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [button setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 25, 21)];

    if(label != nil) {
        [label setTextColor: button.tintColor];                    
        [button addSubview:label];
    }

    UIBarButtonItem *newBackButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
    [label release];
    return newBackButton;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried to change `textColor` directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution I could come up with was to disable the label when the modal view controller gets presented. When the modal get dismissed, I replace the toolbar menu item (by calling `getCartBarButtonItemWithDelegate`) again, with a fresh, enabled label.

This way I didnt have to try and match the color that it *should* be. Also, this *should* ensure future versions of iOS will color the link appropriately, should the link (and disabled link) colors ever change.